# После переноса перестали загружаться изображения

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

После переноса сайта на другой аккаунт хостинга (причем хостинг до переноса был тот же), на сайте вордпрес перестали загружаться изображения в библиотеку через админку.

Самое интересное, что изображения появляются в папке uploads, но в админке появляется ошибка - **Во время загрузки произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку позже.**

Менял права на папку uploads и все вложенные в нее папки на 777, 775, 755 - ничего не помогает. Менял тему, отключал все плагины - тоже не помогает.

**Кстати, в библиотеке не видно изображений которые были загружены до переноса. Просто 0 фото, и бесконечно крутится иконка загрузки**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в логах что пишет? Насколько я знаю, там промежуточный этап загрузка в temp, а уже из temp в upload.

Comment: Видел я такое, но квк лечил, уже не помню. Что в консоли браузера? Что с правами пользователя на базу данных?

Answer (score 1):

А понял! Там 100% проблема вот в чем. Там есть указание пути до картинок.

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'syte1/images' );
```

Надо заменить на syte2/image. А так же проверить другие пути.

```
define('WP_HOME', '???'); 
define('WP_SITEURL', '???');
```

PS Только что попробовал та же самая ситуация. Менял в коде, но вроде еще можно в панельке в настройках.

Comment: это где? 
define( 'UPLOADS', 'syte1/images' );
define('WP_HOME', '???'); 
define('WP_SITEURL', '???');

у меня таких строк нет нигде вроде, в wp-config нет.
да и define( 'UPLOADS', 'syte1/images' ); это вроде из старых версий вордпресс, в новых хранится все в БД, как и siteurl

Comment: этот же сайт переносил с локалхоста на хостинг, было все ОК, через какое то время перенес ЭТОТ ЖЕ сайт с локалхоста НА ЭТОТ ЖЕ ХОСТИНГ, просто на другой аккаунт - появилась ошибка с загрузкой файлов

Answer (score 0):

Причина в некорректном переносе. Не были исправлены пути и сериализованные данные.
Переносить нужно с пом плагинов миргации. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: не первый раз переношу, все до этого было корректно. какие пути не исправлены? в sql дампе адрес сайта везде изменен, а больше и ничего менять не надо. сколько лет переносил вручную, было все ок

Comment: этот же сайт переносил с локалхоста на хостинг, было все ОК, через какое то время перенес ЭТОТ ЖЕ сайт с локалхоста НА ЭТОТ ЖЕ ХОСТИНГ, просто на другой аккаунт - появилась ошибка с загрузкой файлов

Comment: Мне-то зачем эти оправдания, зачем знать куда ты переносил (тем более не говоря КАК)? Я говорю как делать правильно и почему возникают проблемы. А слушать или нет, учить матчать или забить - дело твоё. Да, пути - это пути к файлам. Относительно корня сервера. И это наиболее ВЕРОЯТНАЯ причина, но не единственная из возможных.

Comment: сделал перенос этим плагином миграции.
ничего не поменялось.
изображения все равно не загружаются

Comment: Ну а html-код посмотреть?

Comment: html код чего? не понял

Comment: Страницы вестимо. Увидеть адреса несуществующих/недоступных картинок.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в аминку, в раздел постоянные ссылки, и там выберите нужную схему формирования урлов. Затем - сохраните настройки и все заработает.

Если уже выбрана нужная вам схема, то выберите другую, сохраните, а затем выберите нужную вам и сохраните еще раз.

Comment: попробовал. ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

В таблице wp_posts нашел записи с нулевым ID

Удалил через phpmyadmin по запросу

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='0'

Стали отображаться картинки за март и февраль.

Попробовал опять загрузить картинку Грузит картинку с параметром ; ;

И в базе не проставляется ID после 419 грузит с 0 ID.

В таблице wp_posts отсутствовал уникальный столбец.

После запроса

ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD newid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

Стали нормально загружаться картинки на сайт. Ошибка с отображением исчезла.

Странно как то в ID наблюдаются проскоки между номерами
и довольно сильные после запроса новый ID показывает 203 записи а просто ID
показывает 419 номер.

Comment: Фиг там было по всей базе в некоторых таблицах исчезли первичные ключи, восстановление резервной базы данных помогло решить проблему.